# Self-compiled Roslyn build performance: Not as fast as originally shipped Roslyn version

Tags: .net, msbuild, roslyn

#### What I am doing in one sentence

Checking out the branch `Update-1` from the [Roslyn github repository](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn.git), building the csc.exe, and compiling a random Solution with the csc.exe version I just built myself.

#### Expected result

I expect the performance to be comparable to the original Roslyn version which was shipped with VS 2015 Update 1, located in the path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin`

#### Actual result

The build performance of the Roslyn version I built myself is significantly worse, compared to the original one. In the solution I used in my tests: roughly 30 seconds vs. 65 seconds.

#### My procedure in more detail

- Cloned https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn.git and checked out branch update-1
- Built Roslyn using `Release` configuration (tried with both, `Mixed Configuration` as well as `x64` for the solution platform.)
- To compile a test solution, I altered all project files to use a specific location for the csc path:

  `<CscToolPath>C:\Path\To\Output\Location\Of\Roslyn\Binaries\</CscToolPath>`
- For testing purposes I am building the test solution from command line with

  `MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild /m:1 /verbosity:m MySolutionName.sln`
- I am currently also doing a clean before:

  `MSBuild.exe /t:Clean /m:1 /verbosity:m MySolutionName.sln`
- To test against the original compiler, shipped with VS 2015 Update 1, I am changing the configuration in the project files to:

  `<CscToolPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\</CscToolPath>`

#### Questions

- What can I do to to achieve a similar performance with my self-compiled Roslyn version, like with the originally shipped Roslyn dlls?
- Are there any further things (like optimizations etc.) to be considered when building Roslyn itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The biggest difference is that the official compiler installed by Visual Studio in NGEN compiled as part of the install.

However, even if you NGEN, you won't get exactly equivalent results, because Microsoft has profile guided training data to support partial NGEN, in order to get a good balance between binary size and JIT time that isn't part of the public repo (similar to signing with the official Microsoft private key).

Comment: I ngen-compiled it (signed the required assemblies before) and now the performance is comparable with the original csc. In my first tests it was even a bit faster. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Kevin's Answer which is totally correct, here are a few more details on signing/NGEN compiling Roslyn binaries, as this may be interesting for other people.

- To NGEN compile the binaries, they must have a strong name, which means they have to be signed
- Normally, Roslyn binaries are delay-signed with the Microsoft private key, as Kevin also pointed out.
- So we have to use our own key pair for signing
- The corresponding configuration can be found in Roslyn repo in the file **build\Targets\VSL.Imports.targets**
- For testing purposes, we can then replace this section:

```xml
<Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(SignAssembly)' == 'true'">
      <Choose>
        <!-- Shipping binaries in an "official" build are delay-signed with the MS key; later, the signing
             system will finish the strong-name signing. -->
        <When Condition="'$(NonShipping)' != 'true'">
          <PropertyGroup>
            <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>$(VSLToolsPath)\Strong Name Keys\35MSSharedLib1024.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
            <DelaySign>true</DelaySign>
            <PublicKey>0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100b5fc90e7027f67871e773a8fde8938c81dd402ba65b9201d60593e96c492651e889cc13f1415ebb53fac1131ae0bd333c5ee6021672d9718ea31a8aebd0da0072f25d87dba6fc90ffd598ed4da35e44c398c454307e8e33b8426143daec9f596836f97c8f74750e5975c64e2189f45def46b2a2b1247adc3652bf5c308055da9</PublicKey>
            <PublicKeyToken>31BF3856AD364E35</PublicKeyToken>
          </PropertyGroup>
        </When>

        <!-- Non-shipping binaries are simply signed with the Roslyn internal key. -->
        <Otherwise>
          <PropertyGroup>
            <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>$(VSLToolsPath)\Strong Name Keys\RoslynInternalKey.Private.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
            <DelaySign>false</DelaySign>
            <PublicKey>$(RoslynInternalKey)</PublicKey>
            <PublicKeyToken>fc793a00266884fb</PublicKeyToken>
          </PropertyGroup>
        </Otherwise>
      </Choose>
    </When>
</Choose>
```

with, for example, this one:

```
<Choose>  
<When Condition="'$(SignAssembly)' == 'true'">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>C:\path\to\keyfile\TestKey.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
    <DelaySign>false</DelaySign>
    <PublicKey>0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100B15B00E697DB995031A740A3E07A0B1DBE16AAEA61E615A013E0381B4D875F97F1792965D58810893F6D4B1C10CBD991FB8E9F1118D9C0C6F0EBCB50462FC25056E194667CB59822C18E9CB0C17DBC573291F05F7C87B51C48B377C9EEE12F6D5B331B235E5D6E3669737B210F7BE245A76B118C23EAD90FC392E4ED9F6CDFAB/PublicKey>
    <PublicKeyToken>6E0B9EF75D28854E</PublicKeyToken>
  </PropertyGroup>
</When>
</Choose>
```

- ...using your **own** key file, public key as well as public key token.
- The key file can be created inside Visual Studio or with the help of the [sn.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23.aspx) tool.
- `sn.exe` can also be used to export the public key as well as extract the public key token (for example from an assembly you could test-sign with the key)
- Then NGEN can be called like this:

  `ngen.exe install "C:\path\to\Roslyn\Release\csc.exe"`

(for example located in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe`)

Comment: it's an old tutorial that no longer fits Roslyn today