# How can I use my own key pair for signing Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, roslyn, strongname

I'm interested in compiling Roslyn myself to use his internal classes like [RegexParser](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/315c2e149ba7889b0937d872274c33fcbfe9af5f/src/Features/Core/Portable/EmbeddedLanguages/RegularExpressions/RegexParser.cs#L81) and others.

And I should also be able to sign the files, to use them inside a VSTO plugin.

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34962251/7206675) a tutorial on how to sign Roslyn, but it's an old tutorial that no longer fits Roslyn today.

I downloaded and built the code from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/releases/tag/v3.10.0-3.21201.20)
But it was signed by:

```
C:\Users\google-dev\.nuget\packages\microsoft.dotnet.arcade.sdk\1.0.0-beta.21161.1\tools\snk\35MSSharedLib1024.snk
```

What's the right way to sign Roslyn with my own key? How can I set `DelaySign = false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access Roslyn's internal classes you do not have to recompile Roslyn yourself.
Instead use [IgnoresAccessChecksToGenerator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IgnoresAccessChecksToGenerator/), it will give you access to all the internal classes you need, and you can also use it in VSTO.

> Generates `IgnoresAccessChecksTo` attributes and reference assemblies to
> allow compile-time access to internals

From [github](https://github.com/aelij/IgnoresAccessChecksToGenerator)

> Generates reference assemblies where all the internal types & members
> become public, and applies the `IgnoresAccessChecksTo` attribute